# Difference between original xgboost (Learning API) and sklearn XGBClassifier (Scikit-Learn API)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I use the xgboots sklearn interface below to create and train an xgb model-1.

```
clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(n_estimators = 100, objective= 'binary:logistic',)
clf.fit(x_train, y_train,  early_stopping_rounds=10, eval_metric="auc", 
    eval_set=[(x_valid, y_valid)])
```

And the xgboost model can be created by original xgboost as model-2 below:

```
param = {}
param['objective'] = 'binary:logistic'
param['eval_metric'] = "auc"
num_rounds = 100
xgtrain = xgb.DMatrix(x_train, label=y_train)
xgval = xgb.DMatrix(x_valid, label=y_valid)
watchlist = [(xgtrain, 'train'),(xgval, 'val')]
model = xgb.train(plst, xgtrain, num_rounds, watchlist, early_stopping_rounds=10)
```

I think all the parameters are the same between model-1 and model-2. But the validation score is different. Is any difference between model-1 and model-2 ?

Comment: I have had the same issue. I spent a few hours going through all of the docs and and all my code, set all of the parameters the same and then trained. Still, I find that the `xgb.XGBClassifier` gives 0.51 auc and `xgb.train` gives 0.84 auc. I have no idea why.

Comment: `sklearn` interface does not have some of options. For example, method `set_group` of the `DMatrix` class which is crucial for ranking has no analog in `sklearn` interface.

Answer (score 9):

As I understand, there are many differences between default parameters in xgb and in its sklearn interface. For example: default xgb has eta=0.3 while the other has eta=0.1. You can see more about default parameters of each implements here:

https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/parameter.md
http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn

Comment: @gofr1: The essential part is that two implements have different default parameters. I also give an example. Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Results should be the same, as `XGBClassifier` is only a `sklearn`'s interface that in the end calls to the `xgb` library.

You can try to add the same `seed` to both approaches in order to get same results. For example, in your `sklearn`'s interface:

```
clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(n_estimators = 100, objective= 'binary:logistic',seed=1234)
```

Comment: I have done this but still no luck. See comment on question!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I gave `10` for `n_esetimators` of XGVRegressor in sklearn which is stands for `num_boost_round` of original xgboost and both showed the same result, it was linear regression though. Other parameters are set as default.

```
#1
param = {
    'objective': 'reg:squarederror'
}
bst = xgb.train(param, dtrain)

#2
sk_xgb = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective="reg:squarederror", n_estimators=10)

# #1 and #2 result same
```

My env was xgboost 1.3.0 and scikit-learn 0.24.1 on conda 4.9.2.

Try it.